# Set two buttons to same width regardless of screen size?

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

Ok, i have two buttons in linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/aktiviraj_paket" 
                android:text="Aktiviraj" 
                android:layout_height="40sp" 
                android:layout_width="160sp" 
                android:background="@drawable/my_border3" 
                android:onClick="myClickHandle"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/deaktiviraj_paket" 
                android:text="Deaktiviraj" 
                android:layout_height="40sp" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:background="@drawable/my_border3"
                android:onClick="myClickHandle">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

So the thing is, if I use fill parent on both buttons, they are one on each other, so i have made first button 160sp width, and second is fill_parent. If this is shown on 4 inch screen or smaller, buttons are the same size, but if i try this on tablet (10 inch) first button stays 160sp wide, and second is stretched till the end of screen (because fill_parent). Can i make this, so both buttons could be even size in no matter what size is the screen ??

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use `android:layout_weight="1"` on both `Button`s. Set `android:layout_width="0dp"` on both. Since both buttons now have equal weighting, they will now each have half the parent's width.

You can find out more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 24):

If what you're looking to do is to make all the buttons the width of the widest button, setting weights isn't going to do that.  Rather, you can put all the buttons in a TableLayout:

```
   <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/short_text" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/enter_manually" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

This layout will show 2 buttons, one on top of the other, the same width.

Comment: This answer is slept on hard

Comment: I didn't get weather its appreciation or sarcasm !

Comment: I prefer using this method instead of using the weight attribute. It is definetely underrated.

Answer (score 6):

set to each button:

```
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width=display.getWidth();
    btn1.setWidth(width/2);
    btn2.seTwidth(width/2);
```

Set anything in xml file then first find width of device then set width half to both button
    Now On every device they will look exactly same

Comment: I think this solution goes against the spirit of defining the layout in an XML resource. Che Jami's solution is better.

Comment: This solution is the best for me better than xml. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="One" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Two" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[These is the example for equal size buttons for side by side can be done from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8259.png)

```
android:layout_weight
```

is used to assign space for buttons or whatever of equal amount for every child of LinearLayout.

Note: It works only on linear layout.

Comment: please add some more commentry to your answer. what did you cahnge? why is your answer right? what have you corrected? please look over your answer and add some more Details. thanks.

Comment: okay @cramopy tell me if you still want detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

```
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:layout_width="0dp
```

it's working

Answer (score 1):

Set android:layout_weight="1" in the containing layout The linear layout should have android:orientation set as horizontal. And then the inside buttons should have the following:

android:layout_width="0dp"

android:layout_weight="0.5"

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my btn 1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my btn 2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A comment on how / why your code solves the problem would go a long way to make it more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can set them in linear layout nested in relative layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bestBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_light2"
            android:background="@drawable/sharefb_btn"
            android:text="@string/sharefb" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_light2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/puzzle_opening_btn_ncvtelen_3"
            android:text="@string/playagain" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and you will get somethiing like that

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can set android:layout_width="match_parent". by setting android:layout_marginHorizontal to a fixed value in a Layout android:orientation="vertical" will make the buttons same size.