# Should I use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout to have 4 objects fill a screen?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am learning about the difference between `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` and am confused about the best way to solve my specific problem. I want to have 4 buttons fill a screen, each with some different action. After having trouble with `RelativeLayout`, I was recommended to switch to `LinearLayout` by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982395/set-two-buttons-to-same-width-regardless-of-screen-size) SO thread. Using a nested `LinearLayout` and the `android:weight` value, I got a solution that does work properly. However, now I get the warning: "Nested weights are bad for performance." I propmtly looked that up on SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives) article, telling me to switch back to `RelativeLayout`.

What's the right answer? Is there a good way to have objects fill an area like this in `RelativeLayout`?

This is my current code. Excuse the extra stuff, not sure what to leave in and what to just take out.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/motherStack"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rowOne"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/redButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/red_button_text"
        android:textColor="@color/RED" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blueButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/blue_button_text"
        android:textColor="@color/BLUE" /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rowTwo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/greenButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/green_button_text"
        android:textColor="@color/GREEN" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yellowButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/yellow_button_text"
        android:textColor="@color/YELLOW" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

I would post an image but I just joined and have no reputation. :(

Comment: how do you want the buttons to fill the screen? Vertically/Horizontally? One after the other or in a grid like layout?

Comment: post the image in postimage.org and upload here.

Comment: I can't post an image because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Keep root element `android:orientation` as `vertical` and then `horizontal` accordingly.

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/motherStack"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/rowOne"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/redButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/blueButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/rowTwo"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/> 
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/> 
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean with this. Isn't that what I already have?

Comment: Well this solves your problem "have 4 buttons fill a screen" and also uses the `Linear Layout`. You can probably try this out.

Answer (score 0):

For that you could use a TableLayout as a root element (remove all nested LinearLayouts).

This will provide the effect you're trying to mimic using those layouts with two elements each, each element having a weight of 1.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use table layout instead of linear layout

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>
```